# How do I get full Report including all the Graphs unlike Performance Center/Load Runner in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have tried to get the Graphs using jp@gc - Graphs Generator Listener

I have specified the following steps for jp@gc - Graphs Generator Listener

Output Folder : C:\JMETER\Company-Setup-JMX\TEST_RESULTS
JMeter Results File: C:\JMETER\Company-Setup-JMX\TEST_RESULTS\Results1.csv
File Prefix : PERF_

When i looked at the TEST_RESULTS  folder, png files are created such as PERF_TimesVsThreads.png ; PERF_LatenciesOverTime.png so on..

But when I open the png file it's empty says "Waiting For Samples"

Please advise !

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite Jmeter report is generated by downloading [this project](https://github.com/djangofan/run-jmeter-with-plugins-via-build-tools) , running the included runTestsWithGradle.bat script, and then looking at the HTML report in the folder at: `./build/jmeter-report/` .   Also, this report can be sent as an email.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In jmeter you can set any listener as per your need , check below please :

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners

Best listeners are :

Aggregate Report
Aggregate Graph
Distribution Graph
Summary Report